# django form should return data based on string comparison

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Here is django form,

```
In [61]: from django import forms

In [62]: class myform(forms.Form):
    ...:     f = forms.BooleanField()
    ...:

In [63]: x = myform({'f': '0'})

In [64]: x.is_valid()
Out[64]: True

In [65]: x.cleaned_data
Out[65]: {'f': True}
```

I am passing f as `'0'`, cleaned_data is returning f as True.

Expected behaviour :

form should return `False` for `'0'` and `True` for `'1'`, How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Why you are not passing initial as `Boolean` value itself? similar to :
`x = myform(initial={'f':False})`

Comment: @SijanBhandari and ? How is passing initials supposed to change the fact that the form validates `'0'` as `True`, exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `forms.BooleanField` uses a `CheckboxInput` widget. Unchecked checkboxes do not send any data when submitting a form, so the `CheckboxInput` widget considers any non-empty input to be `True`.

You can work around this by using a `RadioSelectInput` widget:

```
>>> class myform(forms.Form):
...   f = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, required=False)
...
>>> x = myform({'f': '0'})
>>> x.is_valid()
True
>>> x.cleaned_data
{'f': False}
>>> x = myform({'f': '1'})
>>> x.is_valid()
True
>>> x.cleaned_data
{'f': True}
```

Note that you have to set `required=False`, otherwise the form won't validate for falsy values.

If you are only using the form to validate data and not to render the HTML, you might want to consider creating your own form field class.